# Is there a way to auto-complete the open command in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, auto-complete

I frequently use the `open -a`  command in Terminal to open applications via ssh. How do I make it auto-complete an application's name?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I guess a marginally quicker way would be to type out the full path (just go with me for a while here!!), e.g. `open -a /Applications/Textedit.app foo.txt` (I assume thats what you're trying to do). If you press Tab after the `/A` of `/Applications` and then Tab again after the `/Te` of `/Textedit.app` then that should autocomplete both parts for you as you go. Not ideal, I admit, but maybe a but better. This was using Bash.

Comment: You could also try following through the instructions at the end of this post: [brettterpstra.com/grabbing-a-mac-apps-icon-advanced-bash-usage-2](http://brettterpstra.com/grabbing-a-mac-apps-icon-advanced-bash-usage-2/)

Comment: @DanielBeck Bash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
_complete_open() {
        COMPREPLY=()
        local cur="${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"
        local prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
        [[ "$cur" == -* || "$prev" != '-a' ]] && return
        apps="$(mdfind kMDItemKind==Application -onlyin /Applications -onlyin ~/Applications -onlyin /Developer -onlyin ~/Developer | grep -v '/.*/.*/.*/.*/' | sed -E 's|.*/||g;s|\.app$||g' | uniq)"$'Finder\nArchive Utility\nCharacterPalette\nKeyboardViewer'
        local IFS=$'\n'
        if [[ "${cur:0:1}" = '"' || "${cur:0:1}" = "'" ]]; then
            quote="${cur:0:1}"
            cur="${cur:1}"
        fi
        local found="$(grep -i "^$cur" <<< "$apps")"
        if [[ "$quote" == '"' ]]; then
            found="$(sed "s|^|\"|g;s|$|\"|g" <<< "$found")"
        elif [[ "$quote" == "'" ]]; then
            found="$(sed "s|^|'|g;s|$|'|g" <<< "$found")"
        else
            found="$(sed 's| |\\ |g' <<< "$found")"
        fi
        COMPREPLY=($found)
}

complete -o default -F _complete_open open
```

Third version, which should now both be case insensitive and work within quotes.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with `DVD Player`. Any ideas what's wrong? Looks like a Tab instead of a space...

Comment: @DanielBeck It was missing `IFS=$'\n'`. Anyway, I edited the answer again.

Comment: Looks good. A late +1 for the `mdfind` idea. Nice work on the optimization and fixes. `CoreServices` are probably personal preference though. What's the reason for `nospace` though? If there's only 1 program, I want to continue right away with the filen to open. Just personal preference? Any idea about the remaining quoting issue? AFAICT, that's the only thing left for a proper solution.

Comment: @DanielBeck I always put the `-a` flag at the end, so I guess `-o nospace` is just a personal preference. Maybe we should ping Brett Terpstra or something to finish this nerdfest...

Comment: Thank you so much!! @DanielBeck you too. I chose Lri's version because of the speed. Unfortunately, yours was a bit slow. Thanks so much both of you! You've helped me a lot and made my Terminal speed increase.

Comment: Very handy trick! +1

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` and launch a new session:

```
function _complete_open {
    cur=$2
    COMPREPLY=( );

    [[ "$COMP_WORDS" = "open" ]] || return
    [[ "${COMP_WORDS[ $(( $COMP_CWORD - 1 )) ]}" = "-a" ]] || return

    OLDIFS="$IFS"
    IFS=$'\n'
    local _part="${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"

    if [[ "${_part:0:1}" = '"' || "${_part:0:1}" = "'" ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( mdfind kMDItemKind==Application | sed -e 's|.*/||g' -e 's|.app$||' | sort -u )" -- $cur ) )
    else
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( mdfind kMDItemKind==Application | sed -e 's|.*/||g' -e 's|.app$||' -e 's| |\\\\ |g' | sort -u )" -- $cur ) )
    fi
    IFS="$OLDIFS"
}

complete -o default -F _complete_open open
```

No need to install anything. This works with `bash` out of the box.

---

It will only autocomplete program names if the previous option is `-a` and otherwise show default behavior, e.g. return a list of all files in the current directory or complete the current path prefix.

The results are generated from `system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType`, which is the easiest way to get *all applications* that can be launched this way on your system like that. The list is processed to only return the program names, *which can contain spaces and can be different from the bundle names (even when ignoring `.app` suffix)*

Usage: Type `open -a`, followed by a space, followed by pressing `Tab` or `Esc` (twice on my system, not sure if it's everywhere).

Example showing all the helper applications for my scanner:

```
$ open -a Scan
Scan to E-mail          Scan to Excel           Scan to Folder          Scan to Print           Scan to Searchable PDF  Scan to Word            ScanSnap Manager
```

---

Drawbacks and problems of this solution:

- There are tons of programs on your system you might not be aware of, like everything in `/System/Library/CoreServices`. You might not want to list all of them. OTOH, it's really easy to see and launch e.g. `CharacterPalette` or `KeyboardViewer` this way. *Configure the `mdfind` call(s) appropriately with the `-onlyin` argument.
- <strike>It's kind of slow, due to `system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType`. You might need to wait a second or two before completion shows up.</strike> Now uses `mdfind` to quickly get the programs. **Thanks @Lri**
- It can handle spaces in application names, and quotation enclosed program names, but it's rather hacky. It requires the quote to be the first character: While `Scan" to "P` is valid in `bash`, this program will not detect it. Completion does not work after an escaped space either (e.g. `Scan\ to`), use quotation marks in such cases (`"Scan to`). Support for escaped spaces is only good to complete `DVD` to `DVD\ Player`.

Comment: Wouldn't `mdfind 'kMDItemKind==Application'` be faster? If `completion-ignore-case` is set on, grep should probably ignore case as well.

Comment: @Lri You're right. Couldn't find a case where these results would have made a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Programmeable autocompletion to the rescue! Needed a lot of copying from the [Bash Completion Homepage](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) though, which is worth installing anyway for a lot of auto-completion magic. If you do, you will only need the last function (`_open`) and the initialising command from below.

Add the following to `.bashrc`:

```
# taken from http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/

_compopt_o_filenames()
{
    # We test for compopt availability first because directly invoking it on
    # bash < 4 at this point may cause terminal echo to be turned off for some
    # reason, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/653669 for more info.
    type compopt &>/dev/null && compopt -o filenames 2>/dev/null || \
        compgen -f /non-existing-dir/ >/dev/null
}

_tilde() {
    local result=0
    # Does $1 start with tilde (~) and doesn't contain slash (/)?
    if [[ ${1:0:1} == "~" && $1 == ${1//\/} ]]; then
        _compopt_o_filenames
        # Try generate username completions
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -P '~' -u "${1#\~}" ) )
        result=${#COMPREPLY[@]}
    fi
    return $result
}

_quote_readline_by_ref()
{
    if [[ ${1:0:1} == "'" ]]; then
        if [[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -ge 4 ]]; then
            # Leave out first character
            printf -v $2 %s "${1:1}"
        else
            # Quote word, leaving out first character
            printf -v $2 %q "${1:1}"
            # Double-quote word (bash-3)
            printf -v $2 %q ${!2}
        fi
    elif [[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -le 3 && ${1:0:1} == '"' ]]; then
        printf -v $2 %q "${1:1}"
    else
        printf -v $2 %q "$1"
    fi

    # If result becomes quoted like this: $'string', re-evaluate in order to
    # drop the additional quoting.  See also: http://www.mail-archive.com/
    # bash-completion-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org/msg01942.html
    [[ ${!2:0:1} == '$' ]] && eval $2=${!2}
} # _quote_readline_by_ref()

_filedir()
{
    local i IFS=$'\n' xspec

    _tilde "$cur" || return 0

    local -a toks
    local quoted tmp

    _quote_readline_by_ref "$cur" quoted
    toks=( ${toks[@]-} $(
        compgen -d -- "$quoted" | {
            while read -r tmp; do
                printf '%s\n' $tmp
            done
        }
    ))

    if [[ "$1" != -d ]]; then
        # Munge xspec to contain uppercase version too
        [[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -ge 4 ]] && \
            xspec=${1:+"!*.@($1|${1^^})"} || \
            xspec=${1:+"!*.@($1|$(printf %s $1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'))"}
        toks=( ${toks[@]-} $( compgen -f -X "$xspec" -- $quoted) )
    fi
    [ ${#toks[@]} -ne 0 ] && _compopt_o_filenames

    COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]}" "${toks[@]}" )
} # _filedir()

# only the following is needed if bash-autocompletion is already installed
_open ()
{
    local cur;

    cur=$2;

    COMPREPLY=();
    if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 2 ]; then
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(/bin/ls /Applications)" -- $cur ));
        return 0
    fi

    _filedir
}

complete -F _open open
```

Comment: So I followed the install instructions and added the code to `.bashrc`. Now how do I get it to autocomplete? What do I push to autocomplete? (Sorry, I can't read the code)

Comment: Does not handle program names with spaces (like `DVD Player.app`). Lists directories in `/Applications` as well (like `iWork 09`, as separate entries `iWork` and `09`), but not the programs contained therein.

Answer (score 1):

This comes **enabled by default with the Zsh shell**, as long as you have completion itself enabled, of course. Zsh is included in OS X.

All you have to do is put `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit` in your ~/.zshrc, or enable completion through the first run configuration menu.

Zsh is actually mostly a superset of Bash, so you shouldn't have to learn anything new. Even your scripts will probably work!