# Completion for git commands

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, git, auto-complete

I recently switched from using an Ubuntu box for the last 7 years to a Mac. I have read other posts like [Switching from Ubuntu to OS X and I'm lost](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68848/switching-from-ubuntu-to-os-x-and-im-lost) and [What is the difference between iTerm2 and Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25143/what-is-the-difference-between-iterm2-and-terminal)

Why don't iTerm2 and Terminal complete the arguments for a command?

Eg. If I do `gi`+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it autocompletes this word to `git` which is good. When I add a space and try `remo`+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, why don't I get it autocompleted to `remote` like in Ubuntu. I have to type everything manually after the word `git`. Same for other commands.

Am I doing something wrong, or missing something?

(Please note that I am not talking about the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> shortcut which autocompletes previously typed entries in iTerm2.)

Comment: Terminal and iTerm2 do not complete the command It is the shell and its add ons which can be the same in Linux and OSX so you need to state what your full setup is in Linux and duplicate that in OSX.

Comment: You want autocomplete for git - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/55875/24565

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to get autocompletion on OS X is to switch your shell to `zsh`.

- [Change default shell from bash to zsh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88278/)

You can test things by running `zsh` in iTerm and terminal before making the switch above. If you really want to stick with `bash` you can start with these two questions:

- [Is there a way to auto-complete the open command in Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39221)
- [How can I make autocomplete in the shell work with case-folding?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68499)

Comment: Sweet! zsh is good! Never bothered to switch from bash :).`Update:` Using zsh with oh-my-zsh is amazing.

Comment: ahhh love oh-my-zsh

Comment: For most modern MacOS systems, the default is zsh.  Apple switched because bash went to GPL 3.

Answer (score 13):

A solution when switching from ubuntu is to use [homebrew, a package manager for Mac OSX](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew). In particular, for `git`, you will have included a number of additions including bash completion. This will be true for other programs which are faliliar for developpers, like `make`.

In 2 steps:

1. install with `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`
2. Run `brew doctor` to get your path set up properly
3. Install git and bash completion: `brew install git bash-completion`
4. Add the command return in the previous step in your `.bash_profile`.
5. Restart your bash sessions once the new tools and configuration are written to your file system.

More on [this howto](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion).

Answer (score 3):

I have two suggestions:

1. use [fish](http://fishshell.com), it's really simple and easy

   a. extend it by using [oh-my-fish](https://github.com/bpinto/oh-my-fish)
2. zsh with oh-my-zsh. zsh is already installed so you don't need to do much.

   a. `chsh -s /bin/zsh`

   b. logout and login again

   c. execute this to install oh-my-zsh `wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O - | sh` more info here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

I use `oh-my-zsh` but `fish` is great as well.

Answer (score 3):

This somewhat sidesteps the problem, in case someone wants to keep the Apple-provided version of Git on their system.

You can create aliases in the .gitconfig file in your home directory for shorter git commands. For example, I have git set up so `git st` runs `git status` instead.

Example aliases in .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    co = checkout
    ci = commit
    st = status
    br = branch
```

Answer (score 3):

One option that might help is to use `.git-completion.bash` for bash *git* autocompletion.

It lets you type git commands and then have autocomplete for the remote name (e.g. 'origin' or 'heroku') and then (and more significantly) for the repository branch names.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55886/24565

Your download the file from
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a command completion solution for bash that's as easy to use as zsh + oh-my-zsh, there's now [the bash-it project](https://github.com/revans/bash-it). Which, in its own words, is "a shameless ripoff of oh-my-zsh" -- nothing wrong with that really!

It sets up a plugin like architecture like oh-my-zsh does, where you can bring things in and out of your environment easily and get new things via sync'ing to their github project.

Installation needs three steps:

1. Check a clone of this repo: `git clone https://github.com/revans/bash-it.git ~/.bash_it`
2. Run `~/.bash_it/install.sh` (it automatically backs up your `~/.bash_profile`)
3. Edit your `~/.bash_profile` file in order to customize bash-it.

If you're afraid of a full-on switch to `zsh`, `bash-it` is a nice middle ground that keeps you on `bash` but gives you a lot of powerful plugins to extend your environment with.